# AspectJ Java maven ajc: target JDK should be comprised in between '1.1'and '1.4':8

Tags: intellij-idea, aspectj, aspectj-maven-plugin

I am getting this error running a Java Maven project on a new computer using Intellij IDEA.
Google did not show any useful info.

It builds fine but when I start the Tomcat server in Intellij, this error pops up right away.

I suspect it has sth to do with the java version between ajc and Maven.
I checked my project setting and pom.xml, and compared it with my old computer's setting,(the exact same project runs fine on the old computer).

everything seems to be fine. Only difference I can see is that the Intellij on my old computer was using "AspectJ Support" plugin, on the new computer, that plugin does not exist in Intellij Plugin Marketplace, instead "AspectJ" plugin is installed by default, I assume that replaces the other one?

I am guessing 1.1 and 1.4 are Java versions? but it should not be that low.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

----------- aspectj-maven-plugin section in the POM.xml ------

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.7</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.source.version}</source>
                <target>${java.target.version}</target>
                <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
                <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>com.adyen_services</groupId>
                        <artifactId>base-common</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

After poking around for a while, it seems that the Project Language level in the setting is the culprit here. It was 11 before, after changing it to 8, the error went away.

[image]

Comment: Actually, if you have to set that and it is not automatically imported from your Maven project, then probably there is something wrong in your Maven plugin configuration. If you would post your POM, I could tell you. Like this, you are in danger of running into the same problem again after re-importing the POM after some changes. Always make sure that Maven is the leading system and IDEA only imports and refreshes from there.

Comment: Added the maven plugin config in pom, thanks for checking.

Comment: Thank you, but you forgot to show the values of properties `java.source.version` and `java.target.version`. Depending on your project setup, there might also be the same issue in Maven Compiler Plugin if that is also used for normal Java compilation.

Comment: both versions are 1.8

Comment: Then please publish a small but complete sample project. This is called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (please read). Ideally, push it to GitHub if you are interested in my feedback. Or is it possible that you manually set the language level to 11 accidentally, even though Maven sets 1.8? If yes, never mind. If no, there must be something wrong in your POM.